# device Locale effect on SQLite format

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

When I change the android locale to Persian then stored Date in SQLite database change to persian digitst and when set the system Locale to English the stored date is english. How I can set the Locale for Date to store digits always as english in the database?

Comment: Could you include the code you use to store the data?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be storing local-specific date formats in your database.  Instead, choose one of the formats listed at https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime based on your application's needs, and convert them to your local-specific format at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store Date type in you SQ database? You can store it as Long value in miliseconds and transform to Date each time you get it, so you can avoid this Locale problem.

Comment: Because it’s so hard for a human to interpret a long value as a date and time. For debugging and ad hoc queries it’s much better to use a human readable format.